# Python 3 Проверка на дробное число введённое пользователем

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, валидация

Как сделать проверку на число? Например:

```
a = float(input('Текст'))
```

Как проверить `а`, если пользователь введет строку? При этом мне ему нужно написать, что это не число.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4279)

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Extract float/double value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/385558/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/385558/extract-float-double-value

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Проверка

Этот метод возвращает True, если получил любую строку, которую можно распознать как число с плавающей точкой.

```
def isfloat(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Чтобы дать ответ пользователю, вы можете использовать тернарный оператор:

```
print('это число' if isfloat(input('введите число')) else 'это не число')
```

Или обычное условие:

```
a = input('введите число')
if isfloat(a):
    print('это число')
else
    print('это не число')
```

## Вот что является и не является "числом" (`float`) в Python:

```
#Команда                               isFloat?   Комментарий
#------------------------------------  --------   --------------------------------
print(isfloat(""))                    #False      Пустая строка
print(isfloat("127"))                 #True       Распознаваемая строка
print(isfloat(True))                  #True       Истина - это число
print(isfloat("True"))                #False      "Истина" - это не число!
print(isfloat(False))                 #True       Зато Ложь - число
print(isfloat("123.456"))             #True       Десятичное число
print(isfloat("      -127    "))      #True       Пробелы вокруг числа обрезаются
print(isfloat("\t\n12\r\n"))          #True       Включая переносы строк
print(isfloat("NaN"))                 #True       Not a number - число!
print(isfloat("NaNanananaBATMAN"))    #False      Но не в составе большей строки
print(isfloat("-iNF"))                #True       Минус бесконечность
print(isfloat("123.E4"))              #True       Экспоненциальная нотация
print(isfloat(".1"))                  #True       Только мантисса
print(isfloat("1,234"))               #False      Дискриминация, запятая не считается разделителем!
print(isfloat(u'\x30'))               #True       Unicode - это число
print(isfloat("NULL"))                #False      "Null" - обычная строка
print(isfloat(0x3fade))               #True       Шестнадцатеричное число
print(isfloat("6e7777777777777"))     #True       Насколько большое, что считается бесконечным
print(isfloat("1.797693e+308"))       #True       Максимальное значение float
print(isfloat("infinity"))            #True       То же что inf - бесконечность
print(isfloat("infinityandBEYOND"))   #False      Но не в составе большей строки
print(isfloat("12.34.56"))            #False      Только одна точка
print(isfloat(u'四'))                 #False      Японский символ '4' это не float.
print(isfloat("#56"))                 #False      знак фунта стерлингов
print(isfloat("56%"))                 #False      Проценты не обрабатываются
print(isfloat("0E0"))                 #True       Странная, но экспонента
print(isfloat(0**0))                  #True       Ноль в степени ноль
print(isfloat("-5e-5"))               #True       Отрицательная степень
print(isfloat("+1e1"))                #True       Можно явно указать, что число положительное
print(isfloat("+1e1^5"))              #False      Нераспознаваемый экспоненциальный формат
print(isfloat("+1e1.3"))              #False      Экспонента должна быть целым числом
print(isfloat("-+1"))                 #False      Слишком много знаков
print(isfloat("(1)"))                 #False      Скобки препятствуют распознаванию
```

Эта таблица - перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20929983/2790048), данного [Eric Leschinski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445131/eric-leschinski) на en.SO. Я закомментировал лишние части строки, чтобы ее можно было скопировать и выполнить как код.

Comment: любой `.isdecimal()` символ является числом, например: `float('៣') == 3.0`

Comment: @jfs с телефона я вижу просто прямоугольник. :) завтра прочитаю и отвечу.

Comment: Ваш ответ создаёт (ошибочное) впечатление, что только цифры в ASCII диапазоне распознаются. Выбросите телефон который с Юникодом не работает в 2016 году. Все такие примеры можно сгенерировать иcпользуя:  `[c for c in map(chr, range(sys.maxunicode+1)) if c.isdecimal()]` (набор символов, которые float как цифры распознаёт)

Comment: @jfs присылайте новый, выброшу этот)

Answer (score 6):

```
try:
    a = float(input('Текст'))
except ValueError:
    print('Введено не число')
```