# Проверка на целое число—условие на проверку данных, введенных пользователем

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, валидация

Как в Python 3 реализовать проверку на целое число? (все положительные, отрицательные целые числа и ноль)

Comment: взможно вам поможе ответ на подобный вопрос http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494591/python-3-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc

Comment: Да, в данной ветке уже был, внимательно ознакомился. Все идеально, но там описывают числа с плавающей точкой, хотелось бы то-же самое, но для целых чисел.

Comment: `float` меняете на `int` и будет тоже самое

Comment: Взяв за основу:      print('это число' if isfloat(input('введите число')) else 'это не число')  и заменив «float» на «int» получил: «NameError: name 'isint' is not defined»

Comment: Насколько я понял из ваших комментариев к другим ответам, вам нужно просто проверить, что строка содержит только цифры или минус на первой позиции.
Это элементарно реализуется в несколько строчек.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы *проверить является ли строка введённая пользователем целым числом*, можно воспользоваться `int` в try/except, похожим образом как показано в ответе на вопрос [«Python 3 Проверка на дробное число введённое пользователем»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494591/23044), порекомендованный [@Alex.B](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585259/python-3-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be#comment781875_585259), заменив `float` на `int` как [@gil9red](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585259/python-3-%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%86%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be#comment781889_585259) предложил и [@slippyk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585263/23044) явно показал:

```
def isint(s):
    try:
        int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

Пример:

```
>>> isint('10')
True
>>> isint('a') # не десятичная цифра
False
>>> isint('²') # верхний индекс
False
>>> isint('১') # Bengali (Unicode)
True
```

Это может сломаться, если ввод не строка, например:

```
>>> isint(0.5) # XXX не работает для float
True
>>> 0.5 .is_integer()
False
>>> from numbers import Integral
>>> isinstance(0.5, Integral)
False
>>> isinstance(123, Integral)
True
>>> isinstance(1., Integral) # XXX float
False
>>> 1..is_integer()          # но целое значение
True
>>> from fractions import Fraction
>>> isint(Fraction(1, 2)) # XXX не работает для дробей
True
>>> isinstance(Fraction(1, 2), Integral) 
False
>>> isinstance(Fraction(1), Integral) # XXX дробь 
False
>>> Fraction(1) == 1                  # даже если целое значение
True
```

См. [How to check if a float value is a whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21583758/4279).

---

Если вы хотите проверить, что переданная строка содержит только десятичные цифры и ничего более (к примеру, нет `'+'`,`'-'`, `' '`, `'\n'` символов в ней), то [можно `str.isdecimal` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdecimal):

```
>>> '123'.isdecimal()
True
>>> '+123'.isdecimal()
False
>>> isint('+123')
True
>>> isint(' 123\n')
True
>>> ' 123\n'.isdecimal()
False
```

`isdecimal()` можно использовать, чтобы имена файлов, содержащие цифры, в "естественном" порядке отсортировать (как Windows-проводнике). См. [Python analog of natsort function (sort a list using a “natural order” algorithm)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2545532/4279).

---

Если хотите *несколько* таких чисел из ввода извлечь, можно регулярное выражение использовать:

```
>>> import re
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_string = '2016-11-01 23:04:05'
>>> datetime(*map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', date_string)))
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 23, 4, 5)
```

Последнее, это возможно более простой, менее строгий (и эффективный) вариант для:

```
>>> datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 1, 23, 4, 5)
```

---

Если вы хотите разрешить задавать целые числа в произвольном основании как в исходном коде Питона, то передайте `base=0`:

```
>>> int('0b1110', 0) # binary ("01")
14
>>> int('0xcafe', 0) # hexadecimal
51966
```

Подробнее в [документации `int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

Comment: Чем вызван минус на ответе? Как его можно улучшить?

Comment: `isint` это `str.idigit`

Comment: @AndrioSkur неверно. Подумайте в чём разница между str.isdecimal, str.isdigit, str.isnumeric. И даже если бы не было разницы, то посмотрите в ответе на явный пример: `'+123'`.

Comment: Ок. Но `'+123'` это оверкилл.  Это уже может и не записаться в разные места. Так можно и `'1 + 2 / 3'` за число считать

Comment: @AndrioSkur прочтите вопрос, автор явно упоминает отрицательные числа,  если вы думаете что '+123' не нужно поддерживать, то `'-123'` ответ обязан поддерживать.¶ Даже если бы не нужно было знаки поддерживать, то isdigit всё равно не следует использовать. Посмотрите на явный пример с верхним индексом в ответе ('²').

Answer (score 2):

Про числа в питоне [почитайте](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/chisla-int-float-complex.html):

```
a = int('19') # Переводим строку в число
b = int('19.5')  # Строка не является целым числом
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '19.5'
```

В чем проблема исправить уже готовую функцию? @gil9red прямым текстом.

```
def isInt(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

isInt(input())
```

Comment: Бывал на данном ресурсе и читал про числа. Данный кусок демонстрирует преобразование строки в число. Мне-же нужна именно проверка на то, что переменная является целым числом. (В идеале - условие на проверку данных, введенных пользователем.

Comment: @CD4 ну а эта строчка `int('19.5')` тогда для чего здесь?

Comment: Как эту строку возможно реализовать в виде условия на проверку?

Comment: Нужно просто изменить функцию из комментария `Alex.B`, воспользовавшись советом `gil9red`

Comment: Следуйте pep-8 соглашениям имён, если нет особых причин их нарушать в вашем конкретном случае. Не используйте camelCase для имён функций, можно `isint()` назвать вместо этого.

Answer (score 2):

принимает числовые значения

```
def isInt(n):
    return int(n) == float(n)


>>> isInt(122)
True
>>> isInt(12.2)
False
>>> isInt(12.0)
True
>>>
```

Comment: это неверно. 1- это вместо возвращения False, выбрасывает исключения для некоторых строк ('a') 2- даже если строку с целым числом передать, ломается (попробуйте число больше `2**53`). float имеют ограниченную точность в Питоне, а int могут быть сколь угодно большими. Подробнее [Ляп в Питоне: x + 1.0 < x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748183/23044)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй через `type(variable)`.

Например: `if type(var) is int: print('Variable: %d is int!' % var)`

Answer (score 0):

Проверка на самом деле простая. Как вы помните, любое деление или возведение в степень в Python некоего выражения приведёт к тому, что результат операции примет тип переменной  float. Функция type() окажется бесполезной. Я для проверки пользуюсь простой формулой деления целого числа на число с плавающей запятой. Если число целое, то результат будет равен 1.0, а иначе отличаться от единицы. Вот пример кода для проверки возведённого в степень числа:

```
number = 170
a=number**(1/2)
if int(a)/float(a)==1.0:
    print('Квадратный корень из',int(number),'равен', int(number**(1/2)), ' - является целым числом')
else:
    print('Квадратный корень из',int(number),'- не целое число.')
```

Answer (score -1):

Используйте стандартный метод

```
>>> (-2.0).is_integer()
True
>>> (3.2).is_integer()
False
```

Comment: Использую русский язык в ответах, пожалуйста))