# Ляп в Питоне: x + 1.0 < x

Tags: python

При смешивании типов возможно [неочевидное поведение](https://github.com/cosmologicon/pywat#mixing-numerical-types):

```
>>> x = (1 << 53) + 1
>>> x + 1.0 < x
True
```

Казалось бы, что `x + 1.0` не меньше просто `x`, поэтому ожидаемый результат сравнения `False`, но возвращается `True`. Почему?

Comment: https://repl.it/repls/ZigzagWebbedAurochs

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Why does 9007199254740993 != 9007199254740993.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31437463/4279)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**Кратко:** *9007199254740992.0 < 9007199254740993*

При сложении, числа к общему типу приводятся в Питоне. `x` (int) конвертируется во float так как `1.0` это float. `x` непредставим точно в виде float, поэтому выбирается ближайшее (меньшее здесь) представимое число: x -> float(x-1). Поэтому сумма получается неточной:

```
x+1.0 -> float(x-1)+1.0 -> (x) -> float(x-1)
```

Сравнение float < int происходит точно. Значение `x` (int) математически больше `x+1.0` (float).

---

Целые числа в Питоне имеют бесконечную точность (могут быть сколь угодно большими). Но вещественные числа, такие как создаваемые `1.0` константой в исходном коде, представлены типом `float`— числами с плавающей точкой.

[`x` слагаемое во float здесь превращается](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#arithmetic-conversions):

> otherwise, if either argument is a floating point number, the other is converted to floating point;

[ещё до вычисления суммы](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

> the numbers are converted to a common type and then added together

```
>>> x
9007199254740993
>>> float(x) == float(x-1) == 9007199254740992.0
True
>>> x+1.0 == float(x) + 1 == float(x-1) + 1 == float(x) == float(x-1)
True
```

На IEEE 754 платформах, где Python float соответствует [числам с двойной точностью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8):

```
>>> sys.float_info.radix
2
>>> sys.float_info.mant_dig
53
>>> float(1<<53).hex()  # точно представлено
'0x1.0000000000000p+53'
>>> float((1<<53) + 1).hex()  # непредставимо точно, округляется
'0x1.0000000000000p+53'
>>> (float((1<<53) + 1) + 1.0).hex()  # двойное округление
'0x1.0000000000000p+53'
```

Вывод показывает, что `float(x)` и `x + 1.0` представлены  как одно и то же число: `float(x-1)`. Подробнее см. вопрос [Отображение числа 9223372036854775807](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690856/23044).

`x` является `int`, поэтому величина `(1<<53)+1` точно представлена (9007199254740993).

[Сравнение математически точно происходит без приведения типов](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons):

> The objects do not need to have the same type.
>   ...
>   Within the limits of the types involved, they compare mathematically (algorithmically) correct without loss of precision.

```
>>> 9007199254740992.0 < 9007199254740993
True
```

Вот так `x + 1.0` может быть меньше `x` в Питоне.

Comment: "При сложении, слагаемые к общему типу приводятся в Питоне." - Учитель Йода, перелогиньтесь.

Comment: @Александр, обратная польская нотация же)