# В Си '0' == 48 (если ASCII). Почему '0' != 48 в Питоне?

Tags: python, c

Почему в питоне нельзя приравнять(по смыслу):  `'0' == 48`?
Ведь по кодировке **ASCII** это одно и тоже.
Просто в `C` же можно, а почему тут не действует?

Comment: Может дело в том, что в Питоне строки допустимы и в одиночных кавычках?

Comment: https://ideone.com/CI257m ---- а вот мой код

Comment: Очень хорошо. Но код надо писать в вопросе. И даже если вы это сделаете, строки в питоне все равно можно будет писать в одиночных кавычках.

Comment: наверное потому что это не "с"? Бросайте вы изучать Python - он вам не нужен. ;-) Язык "c"  лучше ведь, правда?

Comment: @Vasyl Kolomiets, спасибо, но ведь питон проще, чем все так и выигрывает си?????!!!(я сам за си, но просто аргументы хочу от других людей услышать))))

Comment: кстати, да все так и можно приравнять по смыслу!!! chr(48) выдает в консоли '0' , но у меня в проге что-то не работает(((((

Comment: мне нужно считать из файла матрицу символов в матрицу, которая в проге и уже закинуть туда не символы, а числа!!!!!

Comment: @Romer,  напишите вашу программу. )
конвертация символов  в целое делается так:  i =int(ch)

Comment: кстати Python не проще. Он умнее. )

Comment: @Vasyl Kolomiets, спасибо, но тогда почему Вы сказали бросать питон, т.к. си лучше?????мой код пока что не работает, походу не только в типе дело!!

Comment: Строки и числа — вещи разные, и смешивать их — глупость. К вашим услугам функции `ord`, переводящая символ в Unicode/ASCII число, и `chr`, переводящая Unicode/ASCII число в символ

Comment: в питоне 3 есть классная штука bytearray, а в питоне2 (также и в 3) есть модуль struct для таких дел

Comment: bytearray - это как строка, но когда берешь один элемент - он получается int

Comment: @Romer: чтение матрицы символов из файла -- это совсем другой вопрос. *"мой код пока не работает"* -- создайте минимальный пример кода [mcve], приведите ввод, желаемый вывод и что у вас фактически получается. Опубликуйте как отдельный вопрос. В сторону: про Си и Питон, я думаю Vasyl Kolomiets пошутил (должно быть очевидно, что разные языки могут и ведут себя по-разному. Если вы привыкли к одному в одном языке, это не значит, что другие языки обязаны также себя вести -- лучше/хуже другое поведение -- это уже от конкретной задачи зависит).

Answer (score 1):

В Си `'0'` имеет тип `int`. В Питоне `'0'` имеет тип `str`. Строки не равны числам в Питоне. Питон — сильно-типизированный язык. `str` не превращается неявно в `int`.

Для сравнения приведите к одному типу:

```
>>> ord('0') == 48
True
>>> '0' == chr(48)
True
```

[`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord) возвращает порядковый номер Unicode символа (Unicode code point) как целое число.
[`chr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) в обратную сторону работает: возвращает Unicode символ по его номеру.

Номера Unicode символов в ASCII диапазоне совпадают со значениями байтов, полученных кодированием этих символов, используя ASCII кодировку.

Байты (тип bytes) в Питоне (3) это коллекция чисел в диапазоне `0 <= b < 256`. Байты в ASCII диапазоне, можно с помощью соответствующих символов в исходном коде задавать:

```
>>> b'0'[0] == 48
True
```

В Питоне, гарантировано `48` здесь получите (вне зависимости от кодировки исходного кода). В сторону: в общем случае Си не обязан ASCII кодировку использовать, поэтому `'0'` не обязан быть равным `48`.

Answer (score 0):

Тут не действует, потому что:
1) в Python обычные строки не ASCII, а UNICODE
2) главное это разные типы для сравнения которых надо делать явное приведение.

Дополнительная новость - в Python нет матриц и массивов в понимании Фортрана или С.  Однако есть специальные модули, в которых похожие массивы реализованы.

Comment: 1- str тип представлял последовательности байт в Питоне 2 (не обязан ascii кодировку использовать). str представляет последовательности Unicode символов в Питоне 3 (их внутреннее представление может быть разным -- деталь реализации).  Другими словами ASCII и Unicode к совершенно разным категориям в Питоне относятся (всё равно что килограммы с метрами сравнивать). 2- в общем случае, объекты разных типов могут быть равны в Питоне. К примеру: `1 == 1.0` (сравнение происходит *без приведения типа*, подробнее: [Ляп в Питоне: x + 1.0 < x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748183/23044))