# Оптимизация поиска наименьшего делителя

Tags: python, python-3.x

Требуется найти наименьший делитель числа n>1. Ограничение по времени 1000 мс.
Видимо проверяется на очень больших числах.
Смог дойти до 55го теста и попадаю на превышение времени.

Как улучшить оптимизацию?

Код:

```
from math import sqrt


def mindivisor(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 2
    if n % 3 == 0:
        return 3
    if n % 5 == 0:
        return 5
    i = 7
    while n % i != 0:
        i += 2
        if i % 10 == 5:
            i += 2
    if i > sqrt(n):
        return n
    else:
        return i


n = int(input())
print(mindivisor(n))
```

Comment: отступ для `if i > sqrt(n)` проверьте

Comment: @jfs спасибо! Тут собака и была зарыта

Answer (score 2):

```
while n % i != 0:
```

Тут вы проверяете **все** числа до `n`, хотя можно только до `sqrt(n)`.
Мне кажется, что основная проблема в этом. Попробуйте безо всяких проверок, просто в лоб:

```
def div(n):
    for i in range(2, int(sqrt(n)+1)):
        if n%i == 0:
            return i
    return n
```

Comment: с этого я начал,  потом сокращал. Минимум убрав чётные - перебор в 2 раза сокращается. Также перебор идёт до корня из n,  просто проверка внутри

Comment: да, данный метод самый быстрый. Тут уже ускорить нечего :)

Comment: @Денис: есть и более быстрые методы факторизации больших чисел, к примеру [Метод квадратичного решета](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: для больших чисел граница неправильная. Чтобы понять почему (одна из возможных причин) см.:
 [Ляп в Питоне: x + 1.0 < x](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/748183/23044).  Лучше `ceil(sqrt(n))+1` использовать, чтобы с целыми дело иметь. Хотя здесь это скорее теоретическая проблема: подобный алгоритм со 100-битовыми числами до правой границы не дойдёт.

Answer (score 0):

Итоговый код:

```
from math import sqrt, ceil


def mindivisor(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 2
    if n % 3 == 0:
        return 3
    if n % 5 == 0:
        return 5
    i = 7
    while n % i != 0:
        i += 2
        if i % 10 == 5:
            i += 2
        if i > ceil(sqrt(n)) + 1:
            return n
    return i


n = int(input())
print(mindivisor(n))
```

Проблема была в отступах перед if i > ceil(sqrt(n)) + 1:

Answer (score 0):

Вариант алгоритма [перебора делителей](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9) c [wheel factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_factorization) для множителей `2` и `3`. Делители генерируются с шагом 2 и 4 по переменке. [Транслировано с D кода](https://stackoverflow.com/a/193589/4279):

```
from math import ceil, sqrt


def mindivisor(number):
    # manually test 1, 2, 3 and multiples of 2 and 3
    if number == 1:
        return 1
    elif number % 2 == 0:
        return 2
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        return 3

    # we can now avoid to consider multiples
    # of 2 and 3. This can be done really simply
    # by starting at 5 and incrementing by 2 and 4
    # alternatively, that is:
    #    5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, ...
    # we don't need to go higher than the square root of the number
    divisor = 5
    increment = 2
    sqrt_n = ceil(sqrt(number))
    while divisor <= sqrt_n:
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return divisor
        divisor += increment
        increment = 6 - increment  # 2 -> 4 -> 2

    return number  # number is prime
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/brython-dev/brython/3.4.0/www/src/brython.js"></script><body onload="brython()"><script type="text/python">
from math import ceil, sqrt


def mindivisor(number):
    # manually test 1, 2, 3 and multiples of 2 and 3
    if number == 1:
        return 1
    elif number % 2 == 0:
        return 2
    elif number % 3 == 0:
        return 3

    # we can now avoid to consider multiples
    # of 2 and 3. This can be done really simply
    # by starting at 5 and incrementing by 2 and 4
    # alternatively, that is:
    #    5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, 29, 31, 35, 37, ...
    # we don't need to go higher than the square root of the number
    divisor = 5
    increment = 2
    sqrt_n = ceil(sqrt(number))
    while divisor <= sqrt_n:
        if number % divisor == 0:
            return divisor
        divisor += increment
        increment = 6 - increment  # 2 -> 4 -> 2

    return number  # number is prime
    
def show(n):
    print(f"{n} -> {mindivisor(n)}")
    
show(2209)    
show(2201)    

# try your own input    
from browser import document, alert 
@document["mybutton"].bind("click") 
def on_click(event):
    show(int(document["zone"].value))
</script>
<input id="zone" value="2021"><button id="mybutton">mindivisor</button></body>
```