# Как написать оператор выбора case на Python?

Tags: python

Решить задачу с помощью Python

> Дано расписание приёмных часов врача. Вывести на экран приёмные часы врача в заданный день недели.

Написала на Pascal, а на Python перевести не могу.

```
program z10; 
var 
  n:integer; 
begin 
   readln(n); 
   Writeln('введите порядковый номер дня недели'); 
   case n of
     1: writeln ('понедельник 8:00-14:00'); 
     2: writeln ('вторник 14:00-20:00'); 
     3: writeln ('среда 8:00-14:00'); 
     4: writeln ('четверг 14:00-20:00'); 
     5: writeln ('пятница 8:00-14:00'); 
     else writeln ('приёма нет'); 
  end; 
end.
```

Comment: program z10;
var n:integer;
begin
readln(n);
Writeln('введите порядковый номер дня недели');
case n of
  1: writeln ('понедельник 8:00-14:00');
  2: writeln (' вторник 14:00-20:00');
  3: writeln ('среда 8:00-14:00');
  4: writeln (' четверг 14:00-20:00');
  5: writeln ('пятница 8:00-14:00');
  else
  writeln ('приема нет');
  end;
  end.

Comment: Добавляйте правки в вопрос (кнопка "править"), а не в комментарии ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Чаще этот оператор реализуют с помощью словаря. Это удобнее и код чище чем куча `if-else`

```
working_schedule = {
    1: 'понедельник 8:00-14:00', 
    2: 'вторник 14:00-20:00', 
    3: 'среда 8:00-14:00', 
    4: 'четверг 14:00-20:00', 
    5: 'пятница 8:00-14:00'
}

day = int(input('день недели: '))
print(working_schedule[day])
```

Comment: [*список* используют](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/780432/23044), чтобы по *индексу* получить значение в Питоне.¶ В коде `приёма нет` случай не обработан.

Answer (score 5):

В Python нет оператора `switch-case`. Некоторые применяют конструкцию `if-elif-else`.
Решение может выглядеть, например, вот так:

```
den_nedeli = ['пн', 'вт', 'ср', 'чт', 'пт', 'сб', 'вс']
vremja_raboti = ['с 8:00 до 14:00', 'с 14:00 до 20:00']

den_vibor = input('''Введите день недели в формате: если понедельник, 
то пн, вторник - вт, среда - ср, четверг - чт, пятница - пт, 
суббота - сб, воскресенье - вс: ''')

if den_vibor == den_nedeli[0]:
    print('В понедельник врач Иванова Илона Максовна работает ' + vremja_raboti[0])
elif den_vibor == den_nedeli[1]:
    print('Во вторник врач Иванова Илона Максовна работает ' + vremja_raboti[1])
elif den_vibor == den_nedeli[2]:
    print('В среду врач Иванова Илона Максовна работает ' + vremja_raboti[0])
elif den_vibor == den_nedeli[3]:
    print('В четверг врач Иванова Илона Максовна работает ' + vremja_raboti[1])
elif den_vibor == den_nedeli[4]:
    print('В пятницу врач Иванова Илона Максовна работает ' + vremja_raboti[0])
elif den_vibor == den_nedeli[5]:
    print('В субботу врач Иванова Илона Максовна едет на пикник, поэтому не работает')
elif den_vibor == den_nedeli[6]:
    print('В воскресенье врач Иванова Илона Максовна лечит свою голову после пикника')
else:
    print('Введите правильно день недели')
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно список использовать, чтобы по индексу значение получить в Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

weekday = input_in_range('введите порядковый номер дня недели', range(1, 8))
print([
    '',  # office hours
    'понедельник 8:00-14:00',  # Monday == 1
    'вторник 14:00-20:00',
    'среда 8:00-14:00',
    'четверг 14:00-20:00',
    'пятница 8:00-14:00',
    *['приёма нет'] * 2
][weekday])
```

<sup>[Что значит * (звёздочка) и ** двойная звёздочка в Питоне?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/594651/23044)</sup>

Иногда может быть удобней словарь использовать, чтобы switch конструкцию реализовать в Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

weekday = input('введите порядковый номер дня недели').strip()
print({  # office hours
    '1': 'понедельник 8:00-14:00',  # Monday == '1'
    '2': 'вторник 14:00-20:00',
    '3': 'среда 8:00-14:00',
    '4': 'четверг 14:00-20:00',
    '5': 'пятница 8:00-14:00'
}.get(weekday, 'приёма нет'))
```

В этом случае неверный ввод приводит к `приема нет` ответу, что скрывает ошибку (что не хорошо в общем случае). Более надёжная программа в цикле будет спрашивать число, пока не будет получен верный день недели. См. [Python 3. Проверка на целое число—условие на проверку данных, введенных пользователем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585259/23044):

```
def input_in_range(prompt, seq):
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input(prompt))
        except ValueError as e:
            print(e)
        else:
            if n in seq:
                return n
            print(f'{n} not in {seq}')
```

В разных ситуациях разные решения могут быть более подходящими, чтобы перевести код со switch конструкцией. [Есть ли в Python оператор switch case?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/460207/23044)

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Кратко

Используйте [**функцию switch пакета sorcery**](https://github.com/alexmojaki/sorcery#switch).

---

### 2. Решение

- [**Онлайн-демонстрация на Repl.it**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/SashaSO-SorcerySwitch)

```python
from sorcery import switch


for sasha_day in range(1, 8 + 1):
    print(sasha_day, switch(sasha_day, lambda: {
        {{1, 3, 5}}: '8:00 — 14:00',
        {{2, 4}}: '14:00 — 20:00',
        {{6, 7}}: 'В этот день приёма нет'
    }, default='Число должно быть порядковым номером дня недели, от 1 до 7'))
```

- Вывод:

```text
1 8:00 — 14:00
2 14:00 — 20:00
3 8:00 — 14:00
4 14:00 — 20:00
5 8:00 — 14:00
6 В этот день приёма нет
7 В этот день приёма нет
8 Число должно быть порядковым номером дня недели, от 1 до 7
```

---

### 3. Комментарии

Как видно из кода, switch:

1. упрощает написание [**конструкций `if/elif/else`**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/780337/199934), роль `else` выполняет `default`;
2. позволяет объединять ключи с одинаковыми значениями.