# проверка функцией на ввод вещественных чисел и аппаратный адрес переменной

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день. Как узнать аппаратный адрес переменной в python? И какой функцией(именно функцией, если есть таковая) можно проверить правильность ввода вещественных чисел в python? isdigit() и  isnumeric() ловят только неотрицательные целые. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Что вы называете аппаратным адресом? Вы в курсе о существовании виртуальной памяти?

Comment: я про вирт. память вроде ничего не спрашивал. slippyk все четко ответил и спасибо ему.

Comment: Если у вас есть два раздельных вопроса, стоит задавать их отдельно друг от друга.

Comment: Вы знаете, а slippyk это не смутило. Он просто помог мне исчерпывающим  ответом и все. Да и вопросы не космического масштаба были для знающего человека. Не хотел форум засорять двумя разными темами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы получить адрес объекта есть функция `id()`

Более подробно читайте здесь: [1](https://pythonz.net/references/named/id/), [2](https://habrahabr.ru/post/193890/), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-does-id-function-used-for), [4](https://habrahabr.ru/post/245491/)

Интересная особенность (по первой ссылке):

> **Заметки к реализации из CPython**
>
> Идентификатор является адресом объекта в памяти.
>
> Следует иметь в виду, что некоторые объекты могут иметь один и тот же идентификатор, например: мелкие целые (с -5 по 256), True и False.

```
a = 1
b = 1

id(a) == id(b)  # True

a = 257
b = 257

id(a) == id(b)  # False
```

По поводу проверки уже был такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494591/python-3-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC):

```
def isfloat(value):
    try:
        float(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


def isint(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


x = '156'
isint(x) # True
isfloat(x) # False

x = '156.0'
isint(x) # False
isfloat(x) # True
```

Comment: спасибо. Я не нашел такого ранее данного ответа. Наверное плохо искал.

Comment: @dio4 в тему [кэширования маленьких int в CPython](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/571490/23044)

Comment: @ jfs Понял, спасибо. Но я не вел речь за маленькие int. Меня интересовало  получение адреса переменной (именованной области памяти) или ссылки на такую область. И может дополните ответ slippyk - что это за число такое получается при выводе id() ? В какой системе счисления? спасибо заранее.

Comment: @dio4 Return the “identity” of an object. This is an **integer** which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

CPython implementation detail: _This is the address of the object in memory_.

Comment: @dio4 `type(id(x)) # <class 'int'>` - число в десятичной системе, адрес объекта в памяти для CPython (уникальный идентификатор объекта)

Comment: @slippyk и снова очень благодарю