# Распознавание вводимых данных в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать простую программу на Python 3. Пользователь вводит возраст - получает от программы ответ. Вот пример:

```
age = input("How old are you?")
if age.isdigit() is True:
    print('Nice! You are', age, 'y.o. dude!')
elif age.isalpha() is True:
    print('Please try to type digits only!')
else:
    print('You are trolling me?')
```

Вопрос: как должен выглядеть наиболее корректный вариант кода программы, где с помощью еще одного elif, пользователь при вводе, например, 16.7 получит ответ 'You are approximately 17 y.o. dude'?

Comment: Немного не по теме, но правильно писать `Are you trolling me?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def is_float(a)
    try:
        float(a)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

age = input("How old are you?")
if age.isdigit():
    print('Nice! You are', age, 'y.o. dude!')
elif is_float(age):
    # 0.5 он округляет в большую сторону до единицы
    print ('You are approximately {0} y.o. dude'.format(round(float(age))))
elif age.isalpha():
    print('Please try to type digits only!')
else:
    print('Are you trolling me?')
```

Comment: вместо `if cond is True:` следует писать `if cond:` в большинстве случаев¶  Вместо `age.replace(".","").isdigit()` лучше `try: float(age)..` использовать или по меньшей мере `isdecimal()`, а не `isdigit()`. См.
[Python 3. Проверка на целое число—условие на проверку данных, введенных пользователем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/585259/23044) и [Python 3 Проверка на дробное число введённое пользователем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/494591/23044)

Comment: Обновил ответ по рекомендации @jfs